# Social sharing link (like in StackOverflow) for Django

Tags: django

I'd like to add the ability to share a particular Model object via a link and social media as Stack Overflow does when you click the `share` link below. I like the way it pops out of the page like that with the link.

Is there a module for Django that can perform a similar function.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that's just Javascript/jQuery

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with javascript code you can get from the developers section of [twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-for-websites), [Google+](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/) or [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/).  I've just added it to my site and it's pretty easy, you can customize the code to get a slightly different look from the standard buttons or you can completely customize it (like Stackoverflow have done).